# Stop Wordpress Redirection From /keyword to /some-post-containing-keyword/

Tags: redirect, slug

I have tried everything I've found.

I can't stop webhostingbreak.com/ipage/ from redirecting to 
webhostingbreak.com/hosting-directory/ipage-hosting/

I tried remove_filter('template_redirect', 'redirect_canonical'); in my theme's functions.php.

I tried removing or commenting out add_action(‘template_redirect’, ‘redirect_canonical’);  in /wp-includes/canonical.php

I even removed EVERY line of code in canonical.php and still no result... It still redirects like I've done nothing.

I changed webhostingbreak.com/hosting-directory/ipage-hosting/ to webhostingbreak.com/hosting-directory/test/ and then I cleared the database of any attachements/old slugs that might cause redirect. It STILL redirects.

I'm out of ideas. I've spend 20 hours trying to find answers on this.

Comment: What plugins do you have activated?

Comment: Yoast Wordpress SEO, Akismet, Advanced Excerpt, FB Open Graph, MyReviewPlugin, Revision Control, W3 Total Cache, WP No Category Base

Comment: could have something to do with WP No Category Base , deactivate it and resave the permalink settings.

Comment: You can [intercept and debug the redirect](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/12721/random-and-erroneous-wordpress-redirect/12722#12722), if it is executed via the standard WordPress `wp_redirect()` function.

Answer (score 1):

If that is just one exception you could add an .htaccess rule for it or just use the Redirection plugin. It's not the best solution but neither is spending 20 hours on it.

Btw, Yoast WordPress SEO has the ability to remove the category base, you don't need the second plugin anyway.